# Passing the result of sql query to variables

Tags: c#

I am just starting to learn C# and this is my very first request for help.

I have written a log-in script which has the usual "username" and "password" fields plus submit button.

The script queries a MySQL data table and if the username and password match closes the log-in window and opens a detail window.

What I am trying to do is use two of the fields from the query and pass the content to the detail window for display. This is the code so far:

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
"SELECT clientID, login, pass, name_f, 
name_l FROM FIDS_members WHERE login = '" + 
this.username_txt.Text + "' AND pass = '" + 
this.pass_txt.Text + "';", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();

            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;


            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {

                string name_f = myReader.GetString("name_f").ToString();
                name_f_txt = name_f;

                this.Hide();
                Welcome f2 = new Welcome(name_f.Text);
                f2.ShowDialog();
            }
            else

                MessageBox.Show("The username or password are incorrect, please try again...");


           // Clear login feilds
            username_txt.Text = String.Empty;
            pass_txt.Text = String.Empty;
```

The error I am getting is:

*"string does not contain a definition for "Text".*

I am aware that I may not be doing this correctly but if someone could please provide some pointers it would be very helpful.

Comment: You should proably use `new Welcome(name_f)` and not name_f.Text since name_f is a string and not a TextBox. If this doesn't help, please provide also the line number on which the error occurs.

Comment: Also start looking up `MySqlParameter` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html

Comment: You may also want to relook into the naming conventions. name_f vs name_f_txt vs pass_txt etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably because this line

```
Welcome f2 = new Welcome(name_f.Text);
```

Change it by

```
Welcome f2 = new Welcome(name_f);
```

`name_f` is a string according your code and it seems you're using it as a TextBox

Comment: Hi, the "name_f" is not set as a TextBox, I just wanted it to hold the result of the query feild. If I make the change and remove ".Text" I get the following error:

Comment: The name 'name_f_txt' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @DCJones: that means `name_f_txt` is not defined, are you sure that is the name? If `name_f_txt` is a TextBox you'll need to do `name_f_txt.Text = name_f;` but first you need to solve the "not defined" problem

Comment: I have resolved the error message but when the second window opens the label I am using to display the content of the "name-f" var show "System". On the second window I am using the following to display the var "name_f" content:public Welcome(string name_f_txt)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label5.Text = name_f_txt;